# Using file:outbound-channel-adapter in Spring Integration, can I append to an existing file

Tags: file, append, outbound

We have an application that reads XML from a message queue and writes to a flat file. The naming convention we have to use for the flat file limits us to writing one file per second. This is dictated by a third party application.

Can I configure file:outbound-channel-adapter to allow me to append to file with the same name as generated by FilenameGenerator?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you will be able to soon: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/INT-2668